# Errors on Python chat bot using tflearn, tensorflow, numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, tflearn

Python libs are - tflearn, tensorflow, numpy

I need some help to fix my errors, please read the code and errors if you can help me, I am stuck.

The errors are below, this is my code -

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()
import numpy
import tflearn
import tensorflow
import random
import json
import pickle

with open("intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

try:
    with open("data.pickle", "rb") as f:
        words, labels, training, output = pickle.load(f)
except:
    words = []
    labels = []
    docs_x = []
    docs_y = []

    for intent in data["intents"]:
        for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
            wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
            words.extend(wrds)
            docs_x.append(wrds)
            docs_y.append(intent["tag"])

        if intent["tag"] not in labels:
            labels.append(intent["tag"])

    words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"]
    words = sorted(list(set(words)))

    labels = sorted(labels)

    training = []
    output = []

    out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]

    for x, doc in enumerate(docs_x):
        bag = []

        wrds = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in doc]

        for w in words:
            if w in wrds:
                bag.append(1)
            else:
                bag.append(0)

        output_row = out_empty[:]
        output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1

        training.append(bag)
        output.append(output_row)


    training = numpy.array(training)
    output = numpy.array(output)

    with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump((words, labels, training, output), f)

tensorflow.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(output[0]), activation="softmax")
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)

try:
    model.load("model.tflearn")
except:
    model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
    model.save("model.tflearn")





def bag_of_words(s, words):
    bag = [0 for _ in range(len(words))]

    s_words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    s_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in s_words]

    for se in s_words:
        for i, w in enumerate(words):
            if w == se:
                bag[i] = 1

    return numpy.array(bag)


def chat():
    print("Start talking with the bot (type quit to stop)!")
    while True:
        inp = input("You: ")
        if inp.lower() == "quit":
            break

        results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])
        results_index = numpy.argmax(results)
        tag = labels[results_index]

        for tg in data["intents"]:
            if tg['tag'] == tag:
                responses = tg['responses']

        print(random.choice(responses))

chat()
```

These are my errors:

> C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:516:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
>       C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:517:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
>       C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:518:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
>       C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:519:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
>       C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:520:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
>       C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
>       C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:541:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
>       C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:542:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
>       C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:543:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
>       C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:544:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
>       C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:545:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
>       C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
>       curses is not supported on this machine (please install/reinstall curses for an optimal experience)
>       WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
>       W0805 19:32:44.580796  8632 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\summarizer.py:9:
>   The name tf.summary.merge is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.summary.merge instead.
>
> ```
> W0805 19:32:44.581794  8632 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py:25:
> ```
>
> The name tf.summary.FileWriter is deprecated. Please use
>       tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter instead.
>
> ```
> W0805 19:32:44.596753  8632 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\collections.py:13:
> ```
>
> The name tf.GraphKeys is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys
>   instead.
>
> ```
> W0805 19:32:44.604754  8632 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py:123:
> ```
>
> The name tf.get_collection is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.get_collection instead.
>
> ```
> W0805 19:32:44.612710  8632 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py:129:
> ```
>
> The name tf.add_to_collection is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.add_to_collection instead.
>
> ```
> W0805 19:32:44.613707  8632 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py:131:
> ```
>
> The name tf.assign is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.assign
>       instead.
>
> ```
> W0805 19:32:44.617724  8632 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From c:/Users/iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M/Desktop/work/: The name
> ```
>
> tf.reset_default_graph is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph instead.
>
> ```
> W0805 19:32:44.619718  8632 ] From C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\initializations.py:174:
> ```
>
> calling TruncatedNormal.**init** (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops)
>   with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
>       Instructions for updating:
>       Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor
>       W0805 19:32:44.666565  8632 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\optimizers.py:238:
>   The name tf.train.AdamOptimizer is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer instead.
>
> ```
> W0805 19:32:44.671582  8632 ] From C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\objectives.py:66:
> ```
>
> calling reduce_sum_v1 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) with
>   keep_dims is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
>       Instructions for updating:
>       keep_dims is deprecated, use keepdims instead
>       2019-08-05 19:32:44.696052: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports
>   instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
>       W0805 19:32:44.740369  8632 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\summaries.py:46:
>   The name tf.summary.scalar is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.summary.scalar instead.
>
> ```
> W0805 19:32:44.786268  8632 ] From C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_grad.py:1250:
> ```
>
> add_dispatch_support..wrapper (from
>   tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in
>   a future version.
>       Instructions for updating:
>       Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
>       W0805 19:32:44.936373  8632 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py:134:
>   The name tf.train.Saver is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.train.Saver instead.
>
> ```
> W0805 19:32:45.144679  8632 ] From C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py:1276:
> ```
>
> checkpoint_exists (from .checkpoint_management) is deprecated and will
>   be removed in a future version.
>       Instructions for updating:
>       Use standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix.
>       ---------------------------------
>       Run id: WZ1452
>       Log directory: /tmp/tflearn_logs/
>       ---------------------------------
>       Training samples: 26
>       Validation samples: 0
>       --
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "c:/Users/iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M/Desktop/work/", line 78, in 
>           model.load("model.tflearn")
>         File "C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py",
>   line 308, in load
>           self.trainer.restore(model_file, weights_only, **optargs)
>         File "C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py",
>   line 490, in restore
>           self.restorer.restore(self.session, model_file)
>         File "C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py",
>   line 1278, in restore
>           _text(save_path))
>       ValueError: The passed save_path is not a valid checkpoint: C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\Desktop\work\model.tflearn
>
> ```
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "c:/Users/iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M/Desktop/work/", line 80, in <module>
>     (training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
>   File "C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py",
> ```
>
> line 216, in fit
>           callbacks=callbacks)
>         File "C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py",
>   line 339, in fit
>           show_metric)
>         File "C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py",
>   line 816, in _train
>           _training(True, session=self.session)
>         File "C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py",
>   line 95, in is_training
>           tf.get_collection('is_training_ops')[0].eval(session=session)
>         File "C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 731, in eval
>           return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
>         File "C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 5579, in _eval_using_default_session
>           return (tensors, feed_dict)
>         File "C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 950, in run
>           run_metadata_ptr)
>         File "C:\Users\iddos.DESKTOP-JTOR36M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1096, in _run
>           raise RuntimeError('Attempted to use a closed Session.')
>       RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll increase the chances of getting an answer if you [edit] the question to include the code and errors you are linking out to.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your model may not be saved correctly. Check that your model file is in the correct place - it's currently looking in the same directory that your code is running in. Also try saving your model as `model.ckpt`.

Comment: hey there, i tried what you told me and these are the errors, it seems like it tried to train but didnt save the file.
``https://pastebin.com/Vx4isrCj``

Answer (score 0):

For the warnings, degrade your numpy to 1.14

```
pip install numpy=1.14
```